# How can I skip special kind of files while cloning a remote subversion repository?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

How can I skip on the fly static files like images or documents that I don’t need while cloning a remote subversion repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that mean checkout when say 'clone'?

If you have all unwanted files in one directory, you can use sparse checkout (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

But if unwanted files scattered around repository, then... I don't think it is possible

Comment: Yes, I think clone when say checkout

Answer (score 0):

I create a PowerShell script in order to perform the svn checkout. It uses sparse checkout with a folder list for exclusions.

You can see it here : http://pastebin.com/40VBxjVN

Thanks